# Showing a UMVUE does not exist for the center of symmetry for a family $f(x-\theta)$

Tags: self-study, estimation, umvue

I am unsure how to finish this problem in Lehmann's book. The problem asks to prove that among the class of all symmetric distributions $\mathcal{F}$, no UMVUE exists for the center of symmetry $\theta$.

I have shown there is no non-constant UMVUE for the sub-family $U(\theta-\frac{1}{2}, \theta+\frac{1}{2})$ by showing that in order for $T(X)$ to be independent of every unbiased estimator of zero, it must be that

$$T(\theta+\frac{1}{2})-T(\theta-\frac{1}{2}) = 0$$

And hence 
$$\int_{\theta-\frac{1}{2}}^{\theta+\frac{1}{2}} T(X) dx = c\perp \theta $$

However, the hint given in the problem by Lehmann suggests a UMVUE **does** exist for this sub-family

> Hint: The UMVUE for $Unif(\theta-\frac{1}{2},\theta+\frac{1}{2})$ is unbiased for all $F \in \mathcal{F}$. So is $\bar{X}$.

So I am unsure how to progress further.

Comment: I'm kind of confused now, I saw example from @StubbornAtom that $U(\theta-\frac{1}{2}, \theta+\frac{1}{2})$ with one observation has no UMUVE. But why [there](http://pages.stat.wisc.edu/~shao/stat709/stat709-15.pdf) is a claim says that for $n>2$, $\mathcal{P}$ contains all symmetric distributions
having Lebesgue p.d.f.’s and finite means, then there is no UMVUE for
$µ = EX_1$. It gave two examples of UMVUEs for cases $n=1$ and $n=2$. By the way, which question on Lehmann & Casella's book? I think on Chapter 2, problem 1.9 states that no non-constant estimator is UMVUE for $U(\theta-\frac{1}{2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, the UMVUE for the specified family of symmetric uniform distributions is the estimator:
$$T(\mathbf{x}) = \frac{x_{(n)} + x_{(1)}}{2}.
$$
The hint is telling you that this estimator, and also the sample mean, are both unbiased for all $F \in \mathcal{F}$.  Thus, to show that there is no overall UMVUE, all you need to do is to show that the sample mean is UMVUE for some subfamily in $\mathcal{F}$, and then show that each of these two different estimators is more efficient than the other in their relevant subfamilies (i.e., the above estimator is more efficient than the sample mean in the symmetric uniform family, and the sample mean is more efficient than $T(x)$ in some other subfamily).  If you do this, then you will have established that one unbiased estimator is more efficient in one case, and the other unbiased estimator is more efficient in another case ---i.e., there is no UMVUE in the overall family.

Comment: hi @Ben for the location uniform, $(X_{(1)},X_{(n)})$ cannot be complete since it's not independent of the range, which is ancillary. I wonder if its still possible to show that $T(X)$ is UMVUE without using completeness?

Comment: Remember that the goal here is to show that the UMVUE does *not* exist.

Comment: I think OP is right in saying there is no UMVUE (at least for $n=1$) in the $U(\theta-\frac12,\theta+\frac12)$ family (see last example [here](http://pages.stat.wisc.edu/~doksum/STAT709/n709-31.pdf)). The question is possibly meant for $n>1$ but I am not sure even then if $T$ here is UMVUE since $(X_{(1)},X_{(n)})$ is not complete. Again $T$ and $\overline X$ are same when $n=1$, so perhaps UMVUE does exist when $n=1$.